# Regex to match something based on what was matched before

Tags: ruby, regex, chess

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate moves in [algebraic chess notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_%28chess%29). Here's what I have so far:

```
/
    O-O(-O)?                 # Castling
    |[KQRBN]x?[a-h][1-8]\+?  # Most normal moves and captures
/
```

Where I am lost is pawn promotion.

A knight, bishop, or centre pawn may only promote on the file from which it starts or the file on either side via a capture. A rook pawn may promote by moving straight or capturing to one side, depending on whether it is on the a- or h- files. So something like

```
/[a-h](x[a-h])?[18]=[QRBN]\+?/
```

doesn't work, because fxh8 is not a valid move (only fxe8 and fxg8 are). I could go the long route with

```
/(a(xb)?|h(xg)?|b(x[ac])?.../ # insert 5 more files in place of the ...
```

but that's not very efficient. I want to use grouping, so that I can do rook-pawns, and everything else. I have something like this in mind:

```
/([b-g])(x(\1±1))?/
```

To indicate "the letters b to g may be followed by the letter that comes before or after them".

Comment: Which regex implementation? There is no way to include that logic - match `f(capture)` - in the general case.

Comment: The Ruby programming language.

Comment: It's a nice question, but you are assuming a lot of knowledge about your problem that many of us don't have. If you showed a diagram with cell numbers and moves you are trying to express, it would help. As it is, the question is only answerable by someone who has a firm grasp of chess, which reduces the pool of potential answerers.

Comment: @zx81 I tried to state my point clearly in the last two paragraphs and example. I want to match the letter that comes before or after a letter I have already matched in the alphabet.

Comment: @EMBLEM: It may be clear to you, but it's not clear enough for me (as someone who plays chess occasionally), and others. I suggest you add some examples of moves that should be matched, and ones that shouldn't be.

Comment: `I tried to state my point clearly` That's terrific, thanks for letting me know. But I don't understand what you wrote, hence my comment. How many strings do you need to match? Can you give examples of five of these strings, and explain the pattern in these five strings, and limits, so we can understand the pattern and build a regex?

Comment: @zx81 I wrote out the string in full. It's `(a(xb)?|b(x[ac])?|c(x[bd])?|d(x[ce])?|e(x[df])?|f(x[eg])?|g(x[fh])?|h(xg)?)`

Comment: Not so bad! Hey, why are the `x...` components optional?

Comment: @zx81 A pawn can promote (and move normally) by moving straight forward, or by capturing a piece on the files to the sides. So `d8=Q` and `dxc8=Q` are both valid moves.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. If you want to make the regex a bit more idiomatic, you can turn your capture groups into non-capturing groups (you're not using the captures, right?): `b(?:x[ac])?` But it's two more chars in each set of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! See you next time. :)

Comment: @zx81 I'm not familiar with `(?:)` yet; what difference does it make?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56042/discussion-between-zx81-and-emblem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching the adjacent letter is not hard using alternations, but you won't find anything compact as there is no character arithmetic in regex.

Someone just posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346124/regular-expression-to-match-the-preceding-or-following-alphabetical-character-in/24346189#24346189) out of sympathy for your plight.

The long way is the only way.