# Regular Expression to match the preceding or following alphabetical character in a capture group

Tags: ruby, regex

Say for example that I have the following data:

```
ab
cd
ef
zy
ba
cd
```

I want to be able to match this in a way that the first character is matched, and then the second character is matched based on the capture group of the first.

Each of the lines in the above example should match, whereas something like `cc` or `af` should not.

To elaborate, what I'm thinking of looks something like this:

(ruby based regex)

```
/^(?<first>[a-z])\g<first>$/
```

However this matches `aa` or `ac` which would both be invalid, as well as the intended `ab`.

Is there a way to either modify the capture group, or surround it with syntax that does something similar to what I intend?

Comment: Why aren't `aa` and `ac` matched? I'm not sure what's the basis on which you determine whether a string should be matched or not.

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344875/regex-to-match-something-based-on-what-was-matched-before) from two hours ago, right?

Comment: I want to match the preceding or following character alphabetically related to the first character. So if the first character is `b`, the valid second characters would be either `a` or `c`. Does that make sense? I'm not sure how better to describe it.

Comment: @zx81 Yes, basically I saw that question and was certain that something like this exists, but for the life of me I can't find it, and now it's bugging me. Hopefully that's not against the rules? I figured this was a different enough problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no character arithmetic in regex. You will have to go the long way and express your matches as a long alternation:

```
ab|ba|bc|cb|....
```

You can easily optimize it:

```
ab|b[ac]|c[bd]...y[xz]|zy
```

Don't bother writing code to generate it: writing the whole string should take you two minutes. (Unless, of course, you're @NeilSlater or @AmalMurali—see the comments.)

See, I'm already at

```
ab|b[ac]|c[bd]|d[ce]|e[df]|f[eg]|g[fh]|h[gi]|i[hj]...y[xz]|zy
```

You finish it.

Comment: . . . but for the record: `Regexp.union( ('a'..'z').each_cons(2).flat_map { |a,b| ["#{a}#{b}", "#{b}#{a}" ] } )` finished in roughly the same time :-) (but I think your answer is superior in that it is easier to see what it is doing!)

Comment: @NeilSlater Wow, that's an exquisite piece of code. :)

Comment: +1. This is indeed the correct answer. For the record (:P), here's a [tiny script](https://eval.in/165674) that generates the "optimized" version of the above regex.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ha, terrific! Edited the answer to acknowledge you and Neil. :)

Comment: A shame there isn't a shorter way, but it does make sense. I assume there's also no way of changing a capture group after it's set? I couldn't find anything regarding this, although my search terms might be a little off. (Or is that a different question entirely).

Comment: `there's also no way of changing a capture group after it's set?` You can change a capture group after it is set in .NET. Also, some engines such as Perl and PCRE have `branch reset` which allows you to set a capture group at various places in an alternation.

Comment: Saw you accepted the answer, thanks, glad it works for you. :)

Comment: @zx81 Ah, of course it works, I was more interested to see if there was a shorter way or anything I could be missing. Thanks for explaining. :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `"works"`, not in the sense that code works but in the sense that the words convinced you. :)

Comment: @Neil, `Regexp.new(('a'..'z').to_a.permutation(2).map(&:join).join('|'))` also works.

Comment: zx, I thought I might elaborate your first sentence.  The problem is that string interpolation is done when the regex is created, before the match is attempted. Ergo, interpolation clauses cannot contain backreferences, as would be required to perform any operation on the matched character.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Always nice to hear from you. That's another way to put it. :)

Comment: @CarySwoverland: That doesn't work, it generates matches OP does not want, such as 'yr'. However, `Regexp.union( ('a'..'z').each_cons(2).flat_map { |c| c.permutation.map(&:join) } )` would work if you want to get that `permutation` in there for maximum Ruby doc lookup required.

Comment: Thanks, Neil.  What was I thinking?  Maybe it was `Regexp.new(('a'..'z').to_a.permutation(2).select { |f,s| s==f.next || f==s.next }.map(&:join).join('|'))` and I forgot `select`, but that's not very efficient, generating an array and then discarding most of it.