# Regex that does NOT match something I matched before

Tags: ruby, regex, chess

As part of [a question I asked earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344875/regex-to-match-something-based-on-what-was-matched-before), my goal is to validate all the moves a rook can make in chess notation.

This consists of:

- The letter `R`
- An optional disambiguation, the source of the problem (discussed in detail later)
- An optional x to indicate a capture was made
- The square to which the rook moved (the columns ["files" in chess] are lettered a-h and the rows ["ranks"] are numbered 1-8)

Disregarding disambiguation, we have the simple

```
/Rx?[a-h][1-8]/
```

**Disambiguation**

It often happens that two rooks can move to a square, and one does. When this happens, a disambiguating letter or number is used. So, if two rooks are on d3 and h5, and the one on h5 moves to d5, it is written `Rhd5`. Similarly, a rook on d8 moving to d3 when another rook is on d1 is written `R8d3`.

Files take precedence over ranks. In the first example, if the rook on d3 moved to d5, it could be disambiguated as `R3d5` or `Rdd5`. Only the latter is correct.

The limits on rook disambiguation are:

- Any letter may be used for file disambiguation, and
- Any number may be used for rank disambiguation, but the number of the square moved to must not be 1 or 8 (`R3d1` is not valid because of files' precedence over ranks and should be `Rdd1`), and it must not be the same number as the number of the square (`R3d3` is also invalid)

With the above in mind, I constructed this:

```
/R([a-h]?x?[a-h][1-8]|([1-8])x?[a-h][2-7&&[^\1]])/
```

The problem lies in the last characters, `[2-7&&[^\1]]`. Ruby interprets `[^\1]` literally, that is as all characters other than `\` or `1`. If I try putting the \1 outside the brackets (`[2-7&&[^]\1]`), Ruby complains about the character class with no elements. And if I use an arbitrary placeholder that will never occur, say "z" (`[2-7&&[^z]\1]`), it doesn't work (I can't explain why)

So how can I use grouping to NOT match what I matched before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is long and dense, so I will address the core question and let you implement the technique:

> How can I use grouping to NOT match what I matched before?

We'll proceed step by step. The following is not an exact chess example, but an illustration of how to accomplish what you want.

1. Let's say I want a string that matches letters a through h. My regex is `^[a-h]$`
2. Next I want to match a digit and a dash. My regex becomes `^[a-h][0-9]-$`
3. Next I want to match a letter, but not the one we matched before. My regex becomes `^([a-h])[0-9]-(?!\1)[a-h]$`, where the `([a-h])` captures the first letter to Group 1, and the negative lookahead `(?!\1)` asserts that what follows is not the content of what was matched by Group 1 (i.e., it is not that letter).
4. Let's add a final digit just for balance: `^([a-h])[0-9]-(?!\1)[a-h][0-9]$`. This will match `a1-b2` but not `a1-a2`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: While `([1-8])x?[a-h](?!\1)[2-7]` works by itself, the full regex `/R([a-h]?x?[a-h][1-8]|([1-8])x?[a-h](?!\1)[2-7])/` incorrectly matches `R5d5`. Is there a way to make this work with `|`?

Comment: In that regex of yours, for R5d5, Group1 is `5d5` and Group 2 is `5`. Not sure what you're trying to do, but either of these three methods will fix it: (1) change the `\1` to `\2` OR (2) remove the outer parentheses (you're not using them) OR (3) make them non-capturing with `(?:`..... Might get off the computer for while but let me know how you go